# Wait an animation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, animation, promise

I want to execute something when an animation finishes, so i tried to use jQuery's function `promise()`, this is what i have:

```
$(".title").fadeOut("fast");
$(".title").promise().done(function() {
    $("#area").fadeIn("fast");
);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't works and chrome javascript tool says that promise() is not a function...

Another thing i tried was

```
$(".title").fadeOut("fast", function(){
$("#area").fadeIn("fast");
});
```

But it doesn't work too... any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Both of the schemes you tried should work just fine if you get the syntax correct.  Your first version is missing a closing `}` before the last `);`.  If you're getting an error message that `.promise()` is not a function, then that's because you have too old a jQuery version.  `.promise()` was added in v1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the callback function of JQuery.

Let's say you have 2 div; one is displaying and the other one is hidden at the beginning like below;

```
<div style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:black;" id="Div1"></div>
<div style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:blue;display:none;" id="Div2"></div>
```

You can wait first one to fadeout and than fadein the second one with the code below.

```
$("#Div1").fadeOut(2000, function(){
    $("#Div2").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Here is also JSFiddle sample [Jquery Animation Callback](http://jsfiddle.net/eaktas/3wuter03/)

I hope this helps.

Edit: Modified code for several elements with same class. https://jsfiddle.net/eaktas/3wuter03/4/

Comment: The problem is that i have many divs to fadeout, thats why i use a class and not a id, and your method not works using classes :(

Comment: No difference between using class or id about method. Here is updated with classes and multi divs;  http://jsfiddle.net/eaktas/3wuter03/2/

Comment: You're right. I don't know why it doesn't work to me >_<

Comment: Ok i figured out your issue and updated the code with some controlles. So although there are several elements have same class jquery looks for only specific classes need and work properly. Here is updated code https://jsfiddle.net/eaktas/3wuter03/4/

Comment: Sorry... but again, with 3 elements it doesn't works very well: https://jsfiddle.net/3wuter03/5/ thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it should work, probably you just cant notice that because of fast animation. try with

```
$('#area').fadeOut(3000, function(){console.log('3s passed')})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain the promise to the back of the other animation.

```
$(".title").fadeOut("fast").promise().done(function() {
    $("#area").fadeIn("fast");
});
```

see fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/9b82s6ah/